# Does this matrix and its inverse have the same zero entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ be a invertible matrix with the following property
$$
a_{ij}=0,\quad \text{when}\,\,\,i+j\,\,\text{is odd}.
$$
My question: Does the inverse matrix $A^{-1}=(b_{ij})_{n\times n}$ also have this property, i.e., $b_{ij}=0,\quad \text{when}\,\,\,i+j\,\,\text{is odd}$?

This can be viewd as a analogue of the fact that the inverse of a invertible upper triangular matrix is also upper triangular. It's also thue for $n=2,3$ by direct computation, and I think it holds for general $n$ by using the cofactor, but I'm not sure if if works and if there are better way to prove this.

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as [is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Basically, users are discouraged from asking (or answering) questions where the asker hasn't shown that they tried to solve the problem on their own. It would be helpful if you could edit your question to add a bit of this context. For example, have you tried some examples? Have you thought about the $2 \times 2$ case in detail? Is there something that inspired you to ask this in the first place?

Comment: @BenGrossmann. Thans for the suggestion. I have made some comments.

Comment: I would suggest looking if the adjugate matrix can help, since $(A^{-1})_{ij}=\frac{1}{det(A)}(-1)^{i+j}\cdot det(M_{ji})$, where $M_{ij}$ is the matrix that you get, by deleting the $i$th row and $j$th coloumn.

Comment: Could you show us your proof? for 2 it's clear because of the comatrix transpose, but for higher dimension, it seems to fail

Comment: *Hint.* Note that $P^TAP$ is a block diagonal matrix for some appropriate permutation matrix $P$.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace, following the argument of Eric above, the key is to prove that $\det(M_{ji})$, I think one can use Laplace expansion and the condition to obtain this.

Comment: @user1551. Thanks, could you explain a bit ob how to change it to a block diagonal matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As user1551's comment states, an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with this property can be made block-diagonal with a suitable permutation similarity. In particular, there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that $A$ has this pattern of entries if and only if $P^TAP$ is block diagonal with block sizes $n/2$ and $n/2$ where $n$ is even and $(n+1)/2, (n-1)/2$ where $n$ is odd. With this established, it suffices to note that this block-diagonal structure is preserved when the inverse of a matrix is taken.

In particular, if we have
$$
P^TAP = \pmatrix{M_1 & 0\\0 & M_2} \iff A = P\pmatrix{M_1 & 0\\0 & M_2}P^T,
$$
with $M_1,M_2$ square, then it follows that
$$
(P^TAP)^{-1} = P^TA^{-1}P = \pmatrix{M_1^{-1} & 0\\0 & M_2^{-1}},
$$
so that
$$
A^{-1} = P\pmatrix{M_1^{-1} & 0\\0 & M_2^{-1}}P^T,
$$
ensuring that $A^{-1}$ has the expected pattern of zero-entries.

As a bit of a hint towards the details, here's what this looks like in the $5 \times 5$ case. Consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{
a_{11} & 0 & a_{13} & 0 & a_{15}\\
0&a_{22} & 0 & a_{24} & 0\\
a_{31} & 0 & a_{33} & 0 & a_{35}\\
0&a_{42} & 0 & a_{44} & 0\\
a_{51} & 0 & a_{53} & 0 & a_{55}}, \quad P = 
\pmatrix{
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0&0}.
$$
Pay particular attention to the order of the columns of $P$. You should find that
$$
P^TAP = \pmatrix{
a_{11} & a_{13} & a_{15} & 0 & 0\\
a_{31} & a_{33} & a_{35} & 0 & 0\\
a_{51} & a_{53} & a_{55} & 0 & 0\\
0&0&0&a_{22} & a_{24}\\
0&0&0&a_{42} & a_{44}
}.
$$