# Inverting a specific symmetric matrix preserves its zero entries

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $S$ is an invertible symmetric matrix with the following property:

For the entry in the $i$th row and $j$th column, if $|i-j|$ is an odd number then $S_{ij} = 0$; if $|i-j|$ is an even number then $S_{ij} \neq 0$.

Is it possible to prove that the inverse matrix $S^{-1}$ also has the above property?

Comment: appears odd dimension makes one of these singular.

Comment: @WillJagy I thought they wouldn't be singular if $S$ satisfies all the assumptions list above. Anyway I found this answer very helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756916/does-this-matrix-and-its-inverse-have-the-same-zero-entries. Thank you.